# laravel ajax post issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been working on this all weekend and cant get it to work. I can get it working using get but not post. Im using Laravel 4 and jquery.

My JS looks like this:

```
$('.status').on('click', function(){
var $modal = $('#ajax-modal');
var id = $(this).attr("id");
setTimeout(function(){
 $modal.load('../status/'+id, '', function(){
 $modal.modal();
});
});
});
```

which opens a bootstrap modal just fine and loads the status page. On that page, I set a button with an id of the user, and when that is clicked, I call another JS snippet:

```
$modal.on('click', '.update', function(){
$modal
    .find('.modal-body')
    .html('<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 100%;">Processing ...</div></div>'); 
    var PostData = 'UserId='+$(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data:PostData,
        success: function(msg){
            $('.update').prop('disabled', true);
            setTimeout(function(){
            $modal
            .find('.modal-body')
            .html('<div class="alert-show-success"><img src="../../../public/assets/img/icons/accept.png" />This user was successfully de-activated!</div>');}, 1500);    
        },
        error: function(){
        //alert("failure");
        setTimeout(function(){
        $modal
        .find('.modal-body')
        .html('<div class="alert-show-failed"><img src="../../../public/assets/img/icons/failed.fw.png" />There was an error processing this request!</div>');}, 1500);
        }
        });
```

});

The modal loads fine, and it finds the status page fine, but nothing actually happens in the controller: (I hard coded the 2 in there to test it.

```
public function postStatus()
{
    DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', 2)
    ->update(array('activated' => 0));
}
```

Not sure what I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

First, make your route named for URLs to be more dynamic:

```
Route::post('users/status', array('as'='user_status', 'uses'=>'Controllers\UsersController@postStatus');
```

Then, alter your post jQuery (which I think is the error's source)

```
$("a.delete").click(function () {
    var $id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.post('{{URL::route('user_status')}}',
        {
            id: $id
        }
    );

});
```

And your controller method:

```
public function postStatus()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $thisID = Input::get('id');
        DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $thisID)
                ->update(array('activated' => 0));
    }
}
```

Didn't try, but should work.

Comment: I will update my code and see if this works. I am actually using an external JS file, so I can't make the route echo php, unless I move it to the view.

Comment: @Scott Then try changing to relative url. It won't matter. Also changed the `id` variable to `$id` and altered the json to get that change to prevent confusion

Comment: I have not been able to make this work. I am using Laravel 4, in case that makes a difference. I was thinking maybe I needed to append the token in order to work as a post.

Comment: @Scott are you running a csrf filter before the route? if so, try removing it first. Else, it won't matter.

Comment: No, I am not running a filter on it. I tried passing in the _token as well but it did not seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making the changes suggested by @Arda, but I believe your jquery is incorrect. You are setting the key to be unique, and the value to be `data`.

Try this:

```
$("a.delete").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "{{URL::route('user_status')}}", 
      data: {'id' : id}
    });
```

This requires using a blade template, but that's pretty good practice anyway.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that data value. I have looked at that over and over and did not catch it.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?  Sometimes, looking at code too long just hides the bug in plain sight!